# ordering a has_many collection for validation before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by, validation

My models need to enforce a particular ordering of a has_many association at all times even before new rows get added to the database.

Suppose I have a has_many/belongs_to association as follows:

```
    class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :parts, :order => "part_number ASC"
    end

    class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :assembly
    end
```

As I understand it, the `:order` flag on the `has_many` association will order the records coming out of the database by appending an `ORDER BY` clause to the SQL query. However, in my case, it is also important that the parts collection in Assembly be ordered for the validation to work and that has to happen even before the records get written to the database.

I've experimented with this a little in the rails console by doing the following:

```
a = Assembly.new
p1 = Part.new( :part_number => 2 )
p2 = Part.new( :part_number => 1 )

a << p1    #p1 is added first but should be in second place in collection
a << p2    #p2 is added second but should be in first place in collection

a.parts[0]    #expecting to see part_number=1 but I still get part_number=2
```

Consequently, the validate routine for the new assembly object would not work. Can somebody recommend the best way to enforce ordering of the has_many collection before writing to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enforce it at the `Part` model

```
class Part
  validates_each :part_number, :on => :create do |record, attr, value|
    # if there is already a part number higher than the current part number
    if record.assembly.parts.exists?(
         :conditions => ["part_number >= ?", record.part_number])
      record.errors.add attr, 'missing part number sequence.' 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your code properly, what it is doing is querying the entire Parts table in the database looking for any part_numbers that are greater than the new part_number being added and if so, marking the new part as invalid. That is not the intent of what I'm trying to do. What I need is for all the parts that are associated with a given assembly to be in a certain order so that my validation logic can iterate over them and determine if the complete set of parts for the assembly are consistent with each other.

Comment: I have modified my answer so that you are looking through a specific assembly for parts.

Comment: ok, this still isn't quite what I'm looking for but I think I can build on this towards my solution. I think what I need to do is copy the record.assembly.parts collection to a temporary variable, insert the new part into the temporary collection variable, sort the temporary collection variable and then check for validity. I've been  looking for a built-in method of sorting a temporary collection but so far I haven't turned anything up. I suppose I could build my won sort routine but if there's something built-in that would be best.

Comment: And just to clarify, the reason why I can't use your solution as-is is that the validation is not as simple as checking if there is a record with a greater part_number in it. It's a more complex validation check than that but it requires that the collection be sorted in order for the validation check to work.